# Issue with Selenium standalone service in webdriverio

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am getting error when I run `npm run wdio.conf.ts`

```
Failed to initilialise launcher service unknown: Error: Couldn't find plugin "selenium-standalone" service, neither as wdio scoped package "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service" nor as community package "wdio-selenium-standalone-service". Please make sure you have it installed!
```

```
wdio.conf.ts
services: [['selenium-standalone', { drivers: { firefox:  true, chrome: true, chromiumedge: true } }]],

package.json
"@wdio/cli": "^8.15.6",
"@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^8.15.0",
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the @wdio/selenium-standalone-service dependency from package.json and selenium-standalone service in wdio.conf

With WebdriverIO v8.14 and above there is no need to manually download and setup any browser drivers anymore as this is handled by WebdriverIO. All you have to do is specify the browser you want to test and WebdriverIO will do the rest.

wdio-selenium-standalone-service:
@wdio/selenium-standalone-service is removed as part of the release v8.14.6 (https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/releases/tag/v8.14.6). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

After adding this into package.json error is gone:
`wdio-selenium-standalone-service`